# how to keep running the script settings?

Tags: shell-script, control-flow

I am writing a script called pickanumber.sh. I was setting up the script so I will ask the user to pick a number. If the number that they type is not "8" than the script will continue running. I can't make the script keep running when the user picks a number other than "8". Should I use for loop or while loop? Here is the script that I have so far.

```
rand_num=0
let "rand_num = $RANDOM % 10 + 1"
echo $rand_num
echo -n "pick a number from 1 - 10! "
read pickanumber
if [ "$pickanumber" = "8" ]; then
   echo "GOOD JOB"
else
   read $pickanumber
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `while` loop, or `until`.

```
until [ "$pickanumber" = "8" ]; do
    echo -n "pick a number from 1 - 10! "
    read pickanumber
done
echo "GOOD JOB"
```

Comment: thank you @ipor Siecer. it works. when i used until command. but when i try using while loop, it takes every number as a correct number. can you tell me how to use while loop in this case ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
let "rand_num = $RANDOM % 10 +1"
pickanumber=0
printf "Pick a number on this range [1-10]:"
read pickanumber

while [ true ]; do
 if [ $pickanumber -eq $rand_num ];then
  echo "Good Job!"
  exit
 else
  printf "Wrong, try again?"
  read pickanumber
 fi
done
```